# vim: how to replace a variable with its value in ~/.vimrc

Tags: vim, grep, remap

I would like something similar too this in my `.vimrc`.

```
let dir=“/home/user/Downloads/”
set path=$dir
nnoremap gr :grep '\b<cword>\b' $dir/*<CR>
```

The code above is wrong of course, but maybe you can understand what I am trying to do. I would like to set `path` to the value of `dir` to `/home/user/Downloads/`, and replace the word `dir` in the third line with the value of `dir`. I tried and failed, can anyone tell help me out, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there are fancy quotes; you need to use plain (`"`) ones. Other than that, the `:let` is okay.

```
let dir = "/home/user/Downloads/"
```

You could use `:execute` to evaluate the defined variable with `:set`, but it's easier to use `:let`, because it can change Vim options, too, with the special notation `&{optionname}`:

```
let &path = dir
```

For the mapping, if `dir` doesn't change during runtime, it's easiest to use `:execute`. Note how the quoted backslashes must be escaped (i.e. doubled):

```
execute "nnoremap gr :grep '\\b<cword>\\b' " . dir . "/*<CR>"
```

All that information is part of `:help eval`. Learn how the excellent and comprehensive help is structured; all the information is in there (you just need to know how to find it)!

Comment: Thanks, but when i tried to replace the **grep** command with **vim**, a mistake occurred. `exe "nnoremap gf :vim /\\b<cword>\\b/ " . dir . "/**/*<CR>"`, i am confused why the code above is wrong. can you tell me? thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of mistake? Please be more precise. One problem is that `\b` means something different in Vim. Use `/\\<<cword>\\>/`.

Comment: if i write as yours: `exe "nnoremap gf :vim /\\<<cword>\\>/ " . dir . "/**/*<CR>"`, vim said that ***E480: No match: \<<cword>\>***, if i write as what i said in the comment: `exe "nnoremap gf :vim /\\b<cword>\\b/ " . dir . "/**/*<CR>"`,vim said that ***E480: No match: \b<cword>\b***, the current word is "type.h"(and the cursor is under the letter 'e'), and i can find the word ***type*** by the command `exe "nnoremap gf :vim /type/ " . dir . "/**/*<CR>"`, so i thought maybe vim think the word to be searched for is the string ***"\b<cword>\b"***, not the current word ***type***

Comment: I think `<cword>` isn't expanded. Try `exe "nnoremap gf :vim /\\<" . expand("<cword>") . "\\>/ " . dir . "/**/*<CR>"`

Comment: thanks for you kind help, but it still failed. vim found some strange words, and limited by my ability, i cannot find what it searched for intheworld. but ***grep*** works very well. i will use ***grep*** instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must use this notation:

```
let variable_name = "value"
```

and use straight quotes.

Answer (score -1):

To set path:

```
set path=/home/user/Downloads/
```

or to append a directory to path.

```
set path+=/home/user/Downloads/
```

Path is an Vim variable which does not seem very appropriate to use if you are going to only use it for this one remapping. It would be better to declare you own variable, as path can also have many directories within it which will not work with grep.

```
let g:search_path="/path/to/your/dir"

nnoremap gr :grep '\<<cword>\>' <C-R>=eval("g:search_path")<CR>
```

<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> lets us insert a register here, when then use that to call the expression register, which we use to evaluate `g:search_path`.

Check out `:help expr-register` for more on that!

This will evaluate your `g:search_path` variable on every execution of the mapping, allowing you to change the path and not have to remap `gr` each time.

Comment: The point of the question, I think, is how can the variable `dir` be used rather than specifying the path in a string.

Comment: Yes, I was a bit hasty, I do apologise.

Comment: And you don't use quotes with `:set`.